# python better way to flip key and value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

An api I hit returns a list of dicts

```
sample_dict_list = [{'Hits': 1, 'Name': 'A'}, {'Hits': 2, 'Name': 'B'}, {'Hits': 3, 'Name': 'C'}, {'Hits': 4, 'Name': 'D'}, {'Hits': 5, 'Name': 'E'}, {'Hits': 6, 'Name': 'NONE'}]
```

The function I wrote flipped it like this:

```
flip_dict = {}
for i in sample_dict_list:
    if i['Name']=='A':
        flip_dict['Hits'] == i['Hits']
        ..
        ..
```

result flip_dict:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3, 'D': 4, 'E': 5}
```

I wanted to know if theres a better or efficient way to do this? 
Notice I excluded `NAME='NONE'`

Comment: @DYZ That's a different question.

Comment: @DYZ yah this is a different question if you look at the list of dicts, though it is similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not "flipping" keys, but rather merging the values

Should just need dict comprehension that grabs both values by the keys

```
result = {x['Name'] : x['Hits'] for x in sample_dict_list if x['Name'] not in {'NONE'}}
```

Comment: Or simply `{x['Name'] : x['Hits'] for x in sample_dict_list if x['Name'] != 'NONE'}`?

Comment: Yeah. I like that better

Comment: that works perfectly, didnt know the proper term so used "flipping"

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `operator.itemgetter`:

```
dict(map(itemgetter('Name', 'Hits'), sample_dict_list))
```

Although this won’t filter easily. But a dict comprehension and mapping `dict.values` to the list would be easy.

```
{name: hits for hits, name in map(dict.values, sample_dict_list) if name != 'NONE'}
```